# glob returning empty list when listing files from another folder

Tags: python, glob

I have downloaded flower dataset from a URL using `keras.utils` and it is downloaded in another folder in D drive. I have obtained the path of the directory using `pathlib.Path` and it shows like this

```
WindowsPath('D:/flowers/datasets/flower photos')
```

however when I'm trying to list all the images in the folder specified by the WindowsPath using `glob`, it is only returning an empty list. Full code is listed below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import cv2
import os
import PIL
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib
from glob import glob

from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential

dataset_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('D:/flowers/datasets/flowerphotos',origin=dataset_URL,cache_dir='D:/flowers',
untar=True)

data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)
data_dir

list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg'))
```

This particular line `list(data_dir.glob('*/*.jpg'))` is only returning empty list. What can be done?

I imported `glob` and tried to use `glob.glob` but still only empty list is getting returned.

Comment: You aren't looking for images in flowerphotos, you're looking for images in *subdirectories of* flowerphotos.  You just want `.glob('*.jpg')`, I think.

Comment: Suggestion: Note that since you're using `pathlib`, you do not need to import `glob`

Comment: maybe first check what you get with `.glob('*/*')` or `.glob('*')` - maybe you search in wrong place. OR maybe files has extensions `.JPG` instead of `.jpg`

Comment: @furas with .glob('*/*') or .glob('*') its still returning only empty list. The extensions in the files are .jpg not JPG. The images are further stored in folders of each flower type. For eg: If i want daisy images the path is like this D:\flowers\datasets\flower_photos\daisy

Comment: I got it. I just needed to give the correct path for glob